# How to teach User.IsInRole

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

Teach to `User.IsInRole()` method what are the roles that exist on database.

### The problem

I don't know the way.

### Laboratory

I created the following view to test the role detection:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    <p>Hello, admin!</p>
}
else
{
    <p>Hello, guy!</p>
}
```

And I always receive `Hello, guy!` message, even if I am an administrator.

To get a string array of available roles from database, I created the following method:

```
public class PermissionProvider : RoleProvider
{
    private AppContext context = new AppContext();

    [...]

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        app_users user = 
            context.app_users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == username);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return new string[] { };
        }

        List<String> permissions = 
            context.app_users_types.Select(p => p.Label).ToList();

        return permissions.ToArray();
    }

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        app_users user = 
            context.app_users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == username);

        app_users_types type = 
            context.app_users_types.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Label == roleName);

        if (user.TypeId == type.Id)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    [...]
}
```

(The `app_users_types` is the table that stores the available roles. The `Label` property is the name of the role.)

### Knowledge [update 1]

I've already setup the `RoleProvider` on my `Web.Config`. Take a look:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="PermissionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="PermissionProvider" type="App.Security.PermissionProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

But when I run the application, I get this error:

> This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase.

And as you can see, there's a PermissionProvider class within the `App.Security` namespace.

Comment: You have to add the roles to your database... Easiest way is to use SQL

Comment: You don't have to "teach" it. Everytime you call that method, your applicatin will check whether the input role exists, and if it does, whether the input user is in it.

Comment: @MrJones The roles is already on database.

Comment: @Renan I really don't need to teach? Considering that the user's role is `Administrator`, how `User.IsInRole` will know about that? How it know that Guilherme is an administrator? (In portuguese: Eu realmente não preciso ensinar? Considerando que o papel do usuário é "Administrador", como o `Users.IsInRole` vai saber disso? Como ele sabe que Guilherme é administrador?)

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge I thought you were using either a Microsoft or a third party role provider. It seems like you're makig your own, right? In that case, disregard what I said there.

Comment: If you're making your own role provider, debug your code to see what roles are being returned when you try to fetch roles both for an admin and a non admin user. You may be able to spot the error. We can't do that because we don't have access to our database.

Comment: Actually, I'm stuck on this problem for days — what I need is (conceptually) very simple: separate the areas of my app by roles. Microsoft have its own Role Provider mechanism?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge .NET ships with a membership provider, and its corresponding roles provider by default. But they use SQL Server.

Comment: Debug your code to see why the `GetRolesForUser` method is not returning the admin group for you, even when you log in as an admin. We can't debug it because we don't have access to your database, but it is clear from the behavior you're experiencing there that the error is in one of the Linq queries to fetch either the user or the roles.

Comment: MySQL provides a way to implement Membership Provider, but I didn't yet — I just implement the Role Provider. Is necessary to implement Membership Provider to work in pair with Role Provider?

Comment: `Renan`, the `GetRolesForUser()` method is returning me the list of roles as expected.

Comment: Check your `IsUserInRole` method then.

Comment: There's no implementation on it, Renan. That shame! I'll do this by myself and as soon as possible I return here to bring some news.

Comment: @Renan I implemented the `IsUserInRole()` method and I added a breakpoint on it but seems that the application doesn't execute it because the breakpoint wasn't called. Take a look on my main post to see the implementation. From now on, any idea?

Comment: Are you sure your custom provider is what's being called? You declared one called PermissionProvider in your code, but indicated one called MySqlRoleProvider in your configuration.

Comment: What does Roles.GetAllRoles have in it?  You can use the role provider without membership, but without membership, it has no idea what `User` you are.  You would have to call the role provider yourself and look up the roles instead of Relying on `User.IsInRole`, etc.

Comment: Additionally, you said that you get the same result even if you are an administrator.  How are you an administrator with no membership?  Are you referring to being an administrator on your local machine through windows security or domain security?  Do you even have a log in page? How is the web application supposed to know who you are?

Comment: @RobertMcKee The database knows who I are. That's why I'm using my own authorization attribute.

Comment: @Renan I think you're right — I indicate MySQLRoleProvider instead of my permission provider. Take I look in my main post update.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge what does `User.Identity.Name` and `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` give you?

Comment: `User.Identity.Name` gives me the email that I've used to log in into the application; `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` gives me `true` because I'm authenticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A RoleProvider must implement the method IsUserInRole().  Configuring a role provider as you have is all you need to do.

Comment: `IsInRole()` isn't a custom method. How can I know about its implementation? How can I know if it is implementing `RoleProvider`?

Comment: I think Matt meant the `IsUserInRole` method. Also check the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx

Comment: It cannot be a RoleProvider unless it implements the method